# How to change the content page from within the masterpage in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have seen the other way around, where coders need to change the master page for a particular content. But in this case, I am more worried about what is in the content, and I wish to change it.

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string pageName = this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().FullName;

    if (pageName != "ASP.ChinaShipManagerHome_aspx")
    {
        // then change it here?!
    }
}
```

As you can surmise in my case, I have a button "Search" on my master page. However, they may have strayed away from the content, that the 'search' needs to interact with. So when they click 'search' it needs to switch back to the right 'Content' in 'ContentPlaceHolder1'.

Comment: What do you mean "they may have strayed away from the content"?

Comment: @mason ChinaShipManagerHome is the default page.  However, they can click and do things on other pages, and the Master page remains (which is very normal).  Many pages, one Master, right?  However, it would be nice to click search again.  I'm starting to wonder that this might not be possible.  At least the way I asked.  I may need to 'Redirect' with the search-string in query to 'ChinaShipManagerhome'.  That may be the only answer.

Comment: I know how master pages work, having been using Web Forms for 13 years. I don't understand what would prevent them from clicking search again after having previously visiting a search result. What's stopping them?

Comment: Nothing is stopping them, however: How will it show the results if the ContentPlaceHolder1 page has changed?  The results of the search only goes on the grids that appear here: 'ChinaShipManagerHome'.   Currently the search button just sends them back to home.

Comment: What grid? Your question shows no grid. We're lacking necessary context about how you've implemented this search functionality in order to make a reasonable recommendation about how to proceed.

Comment: i didn't ask for any recommendation per sae. I simply asked "How to change the content page from within the masterpage in ASP.NET using C#?".  And I showed exactly where in the code I wanted to drop it.  You were free to tell me I could not do that.  I think I'll post an answer of what I will do.  Because I think the answer really is I cannot actually do what I ask.  But the way to solve it is a redirect with a query string is the only way.

Comment: This is a good example of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). I know you didn't ask for recommendations on how to change it, but really sounds like what you're trying to do  (Y) doesn't make sense from a design standpoint, which is why knowing more about what your context is (X) might help us to assist you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only way I believe.  I don't think you can actually change the literal contentplaceholder from the masterpage.

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string pageName = this.ContentPlaceHolder1.Page.GetType().FullName;
    if (pageName != "ASP.chinashipmanagerhome_aspx")
    {
        string t = Base64Encode(tb_search.Text);
        Response.Redirect("ChinaShipManagerHome.aspx?search2=" + t); //Redirect with query
    }
```

Then in the 'Page_Load' I added, after checking that the person has not lost session. EDIT: It actually does not matter if its postback, in fact it has to be both.

```
        else
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["search2"] != null && tb_search.Text == "")
            {
                tb_search.Text = Base64Decode(Request.QueryString["search2"].ToString());
                btn_search_Click(this, new ImageClickEventArgs(1, 1));
            }
        }
```

Here it recalls 'btn_search_click' but now its on the right page. EDIT: Must also check tb_search.Text is empty, or you will get a circular reference when searching again.

Comment: Just a simple response.Redirect to the page you want should also suffice. Since that child page will have its master page set, then in place of attempting to swap the page displayed inside of some content control, it simple easy to just do a response.redirect to the given child page anyway. The effect and results are really much the same result anyway. That being the case is why you can't really find some example code to do as you ask, since such a case does not really exist anymore or less then using a simple response.redirect to acheive this same goal.

Comment: In the original wording see above "However, they may have strayed away from the content, that the 'search' needs to interact with."  When they click btn_search, that search needs to interact with content, but now it cannot, because they are no longer on the same page.  So in order to fix the problem, as shown by my 'answer', yes I redirect.  However, a simple-redirect will only send them to the 'Home' page (without any results...)  That is why, I need to redirect also with the information provided when they clicked 'btn-search'.  Then catch that again in the Master-Load.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Perhaps what you also needed to realize. That clicking Btn_search included a tb_search Textbox (as what they were searching for) on the Master.  This data I failed to include.

Comment: I assumed the search box, and code that runs is on the master page. I guess then what does the code behind for the search do? does it search some table in the db, or does it need to do some kind of operations on the many different current child page displayed, or does it care? (by not care, we are searching against say a database table?).

Comment: It populates result-grids that appear on ChinaShipManagerHome...

Comment: Ok, then see my edit#3 below, is that not the effect and goal you are looking for???

Comment: Your Edit-3 was edited a few times, yes I could use a Session-variable to accomplish the same task.  The original Edit-3 didn't look like that.  I have deleted, one my comments that no longer applies below.

Comment: but, why does using session matter, or grabbing the text box from master, or passing value(s) using URL parameters? See my edit#4 in which I don't use session. Session really not much important here, but WHAT is important is I'm still not seeing any good narrative that requires one to swap out the current child page from master when a simple plain jane navigate achieves the same goal and result.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Have you seen my answer above.  Does it actually swap out the child-page?  It does the same thing as your Edited (Edit#3) except with query, instead of Session.  The original question actually asked how to 'Swap-out the current child page'.  The answer I gave does this with a 'redirect'.  You did too... give it a rest.

Comment: Ah ok, then we are 100% clear that no need exists for swapping out the page, and that my oringal suggestion and response of a simple navgation is the way to go - what I stated all along. So, I am at a lost for all your addtional quesitons. A simple, ah yes, I see there was no need to swap out the child page, and a good old fashion plain jane and simple navigation is fine and dandy, and what I suggest was thus the solution here - and quite much the solution you adopted. In other words, my simple suggestion was the simple answer all along then, right? Thus why all your q's in comments then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250816/discussion-between-robert-koernke-and-albert-d-kallal).

Comment: No need to continue the discussion. I simple posted a bit of code and you came back with quote: "I could use a Session-variable". Ok, then you are objecting to that code, and thus I simple posted again without using session. (as if session() was a big deal and reason to complain). So, what more do we need to discuss, or is there anything else that you "just can't let go here???"

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pageName = MainContent.Page.GetType().FullName;

        if (pageName == "ASP.default_aspx")
        {
            // get text box 1 on child page.

            TextBox tbox1 = (TextBox)MainContent.FindControl("TextBox1");
            tbox1.Text = "Hello world";

        }
    }
```

I am assuming that the content control in master page is thus this:

```
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

And thus in the  child page "default.aspx", then I assumed this:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
```

so, we can/should be able to use FindControl on that "main content" as per above.

### Edit

However, it looks like the poster wants to change master page from child page.

OK, then assuming above, and our text box is on the master page, and we want to change from child page?

Sure, then this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this is child page load event, change a
        // change TextBox1 that is in master page
        
        TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("TextBox1");
        tb1.Text = "hello world";

    }
```

### Edit#2: how to re-direct to another page

In many cases, I will have say users navigate to a page, but that is NOT the page I want.

For example, I have a project page, and we can ONLY get to that project page from MyProjects.

so, to deal with above, we do NOT put such code in the master code, but such code goes in the child page.

So, for example, if we say typed in the Project.aspx page (it is a child of master), but I want to "change" what page the user gets.

I'll put such code in the on-load even of the child page.

Say:

```
if (Session["Projectinfo"] = null 
{
     // no project information passed, send user back to 
     // my projects page
     response.redirect("MyProjects.aspx")
}
```

so, as a general rule, you don't want to put such code in the master page, since then the master page code will over time becomes a big mess, since you now putting logic in the master page that in 99% of cases belongs in the given page code.

However, such code CAN go in the master page, and to display a different page, we don't attempt/try to swap out the content page, but in fact just do a plain navigate to the page we want, and that page being a child page of master will thus continue to display the master page, and having jumped to the correct child page, then all is well.

So, we don't need to "change" what content template gets displayed, but simple navigate to that child page in question with a simple response.redirect. Since that child page going to display the master page anyway, then we just achieved the same goal as swapping out/changing what child page we are going to display anyway, right?

In other words, a simple response.redirect should suffice to "change" what child page we are to display.

### Edit#3: button search is in/on the menu bar (master page).

As I have repeated stated, we really do NOT care WHERE the search and button is.

The question REALLY is this:

I have a text box, and a button. User will type in some search criteria, and click the button. I then want to navigate to a page to display the search results.

In fact, this is the MOST basic web 101 question on the planet.

In such cases, and SUPER common? We are to take that search criteria and pass it to the target page. I mean, how does ANY working web site have a button, take user input, and then navigate to the next page in the application? As noted, then we are to pass that search criteria to the "search results/display" page.

So, all is lost here if we can't have simple pass some value(s) to the next web page in question - 100% of all applications require this SUPER SIMPLE skill set.

So, lets write the code to take the user input, have user click a button, and then navigate to a page to display the results.

It does NOT matter if that text box and button are on ANY web page, and it does not matter if the text box and button are on the master page.

And it does not matter if the text box and button are on the menu bar in the master page.

In all cases, the question remains the same SUPER SIMPLE question:

How can I have a text box, and button click show the search results of that text box, and button click.

So, lets assume this menu bar - we can be on ANY page in the application - we don't care, but MORE important, we don't have to care!!!

So, on the master page, this search could be in the menu bar, or on the master page - don't care, don't matter.

In fact, this text box and search could be ANY PLACE in the WHOLE application.

After all, as noted, the MOST simple thing in a web application is:

I have a button, some text, and I need a button click to pass this information to the next page in question!

So, lets add this text box + search button to the master page.

Like this:

```
    <div style="float:right">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="cmdSearch_Click"
            CssClass="btn" style="margin-left:8px"  />
    </div>
```

The code behind for the above button in the master page is this:

```
    protected void cmdSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["MyFilter"] = txtSearch.Text;
        Response.Redirect("SearchResult");
    }
```

Again, the above is something we all do all day long - pass some values to another target page. We could use queryparms in the URL.

And now lets create the searchResults.aspx page. It can be say a gridview of results.

So, say a simple gv like thiS

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID"  width="60%" CssClass="table table-hover" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" 
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And the code for this simple page with gv "search results" is thus this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["MyFilter"] != null)
            {
                // we have a filter, display the filter results
                string strSQL =
                    @"SELECT * FROM tblHotels WHERE HotelName like '%' + @p1 + '%'
                    AND Description is not null";

                SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["MyFilter"];

                DataTable rstData = MyRstP(cmdSQL);

                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();

                mystext.InnerText = $"Hotel search Results for Hotel =  {Session["MyFilter"].ToString()}";

            }   
        }
    }
```

And thus now we can be on ANY page, type in the search, and hit search button.

We get this effect:

[image]

As above shows, it don't matter what page, or where we are.

the simple goal is to take that input, and navigate to the search results page.

As I stated OVER AND OVER like a broken record, a simple navigate to the search results page is REALLY much the same as attempting to swap out the child page based on the current page we are on.

so, no real need to swap out the child page current displayed in the current master page - a simple navigate to page to display the search results is all we need here. So, as long as the search results page also has a master page - then we should be all happy and warm.

### Edit#4: Let's not use session then

So, the button on the master page becomes this:

```
        Response.Redirect("SearchResult");
```

And now in our search result page, we have this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {
        // get value from search box in master page.

        TextBox txtSearchBox = (TextBox)Page.Master.FindControl("txtSearch");

        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE HotelName like '%' + @p1 + '%' ORDER BY HotelName";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@p1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtSearchBox.Text;
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

It still works. I don't think some worry about "session" changes this problem at all.

At the end of the day, we have a text box, and a button to search. The concept of passing values to a page in asp.net? Gee, every application I ever written does that all the time.

- You can use session to pass the search value
- You can pass the value in the URL (url query parms)
- You can remove the button click, and use postbackurl, and thus you can now use "previous" page.

in other words, we are RIGHT back to the most simple concept.

Most web sites will have boatloads of example code that takes some user input, and then "moves on" to the next page, and passing of values to that next page has multiple solutions - you might use session, might use URL parameters.

Or, as above shows, grab the value from the master page and use that value.

Comment: No this is the opposite of what I need.  This is what I mentioned:  This is how you access the 'Master-Page' within the content or vise-versa.  Nothing about this is actually changing the 'Content-Page' itself.  I think the only way is to 'Redirect' with a query-string.  I will post my own answer.

Comment: Your question says: "how to change content from master page". that's what I posted. So, you mean you want to change master page content from the child page then?  The term "content" unfortunately has two meaning, and thus: I want to change child page content from master, or I want to change master page content from child page. Since you mean that child page is to change master page? Sure, I'll update my post.

Comment: I want to change the literal page in the 'Content'.  Since the pagename has changed.
Maybe it should have said 'then change it back?' in the comment above.

Comment: No, it is very simple. I want master page code to change child page "things". Or I want code in child to change master page "things". There is only the 2 cases. See my edit, I show how the child page can change master page "things".

Comment: See my edit#3. To change/swap out that content page (the child page), then we simple use a response.redirect. The results are really the same as a content template swap anyway.

Comment: Well, do you display the search results, or is the search to send the user to a given page based on the search results? The master page code can either display a list of results (on searchResults.aspx), or pop a list, or simple jump directly to the given page using response.redirect based on what they searched for. in both of these use cases, I see no reason why the master page search routine can't display the search results, or navigate to a page based on that search (if that is to occur).